# sniff(wireshark) on scapy printing ping twice with/without python

Tags: python, scapy

Basically I have two machines, in one I the Ubuntu I am running the 'sniff' and in the Kali the 'ping'.

I cannot understand why the code is printing twice, if supposedly only one package is being sent?

I was expecting only the 'Hello World\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' to be printed.

Why is that happening? How can i fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Ubuntu

```
from scapy.all import *

def xyz(pkt):
    #hexdump(pkt)
    if pkt['Raw']:
        print(pkt['Raw'])
sniff(count=10, prn=xyz, filter="icmp")
```

Kali

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import *

ping = Ether()/IP(dst="10.0.2.4")/ICMP()/Raw()
ping['Raw'].load = 'Hello World'
srp1(ping, timeout=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow discourages pictures of code as it's not searchable (i.e. please move them to your question).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's like this:

Ubuntu sends ICMP echo request (first package).
Kali receives and sends ICMP echo reply (second package).